# D3 Not able to render a simple line

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I am trying to create a simple line using the code below. The data is in the form of json. There is no error on the browser console. Also if i set a breaking point in my JavaScript, I can see that data is being loaded into the variable ds. I can guess it has something to do with the format of **json(key with multiple values)** and the way I am passing it to the function linefun.

This is the output in the browser after everything is done(inspect element). So SVG and path are created without the data.

```
   <svg width="400" height="100">
     <path stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="none">
     </path>
   </svg>
```

Data

```
    {
    "-K_4W89HOwyew6pU78Rq" : 
        {  
         "price" : 879.0, 
         "screen" : 15.6
        },
    "-K_4YZzsghq-segc47X0" : 
        {   
        "price" : 799.99,
        "screen" : 15.6
        }
    }
```

This is my Javascript code.

```
    <script>
    var h = 100;
    var w = 400;
    var ds;

    var url = "/Home/getdata/";
    d3.json(url, function (error,data) {
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            ds = data;
            console.log("Success!");

            var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
                         .x(function (d) {
                         return d.price / 100
                         })
                         .y(function (d) {
                         return h - d.screen;
                         })
                        .interpolate("linear");

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr({
                width: w,
                height: h
            });
            var viz = svg.append("path")
            .attr({
                d: lineFun(ds),
                "stroke": "blue",
                "stroke-width": 2,
                "fill": "none"
            });

        }
    });




    </script>
```

Comment: lineFun ( Line function ) is a function which accepts data as input and output will be the x and y coordinates for the svg.append("path") based on the data we pass to it. So for each data object it should return specific x and y to plot in the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[D3 line functions](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Shapes.md#_line) usually takes an array of data elements, rather than an object like you have. You can convert your data object to an array first and it should work:

```
(...)
d3.json(url, function (error,data) {
    if(error)
    {
        console.log(error);
        return
    }

    ds = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) { return data[k] });
    console.log("Success! Data parsed:", ds);

    var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
    (...)
 });
```

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array with all keys on your object (such as "-K_4W89HOwyew6pU78Rq") and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used return the value contained in that key as an array item.

Comment: I disagree with this edit, converting the object to an array client-side might make sense if he has no control over the data, but I don't think we can assume that. This solution adds complexity compared with providing the data as an array in the first place.